# Primary Key is not defined in model, but primary key error is shown

Tags: swift, realm, realm-browser

I'm getting this error...

> 2017-03-26 17:34:49.104919 Mobile[518:254067] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException',
>   reason: 'Only 'string' and 'int' properties can be designated the primary key'

In the prepopulated realm I have all string columns, except for 2 Double columns for lat,lng.

Here's my model:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Destination: Object{

dynamic var destinationSlackChannelName = ""
dynamic var destinationSlackChannelId = ""
dynamic var destinationName = ""
dynamic var destinationType = ""
dynamic var destinationCode = ""
dynamic var destinationRegionCode = ""
dynamic var destinationSiteSlackChannelName = ""
dynamic var destinationCity = ""
dynamic var destinationCountry = ""
dynamic var destinationStatus = ""
dynamic var destinationLastUpdated = ""
dynamic var lat:Double = 0.0
dynamic var lng:Double = 0.0

}
```

Here's how I'm configuring and querying realm in a singleton called RealmManager....

```
    func getHebronDestinations() -> Results<Destination> {
        let bundleUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "realm")
    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        fileURL: bundleUrl,
        readOnly: true,
        schemaVersion: 0,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                Log.info?.message("\(oldSchemaVersion)")
                Log.info?.message("wtf")
            }
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
                Log.info?.message("\(oldSchemaVersion)")
            }
            Log.info?.message("Realm migration did run")  // Log to know migration was executed
        }
    )

    let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
    let naoHebronResults = realm
        .objects(Destination.self)
        //.filter("destinationRegionCode == 'nao' AND destinationCode == 'heb'")
    Log.info?.message("\(naoHebronResults)")
    for res in naoHebronResults{
        Log.info?.message(res.destinationName)
    }
    return naoHebronResults
}
```

And here's the function call in a ViewController...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewDidLoad")
    let realmManager = RealmManager.shared
    let hebDevices = realmManager.getHebronDestinations()
    print(hebDevices)
}
```

Why am I still getting that primary key error, if there is no primary key in the model?

I made this realm file from a csv via realm browser...it worked once before.

Comment: I have not used Realm in a long time so this might be something that Realm catches but is it possible that your prepopulated Realm has a primary key set when your model does not? Are you able to browse your prepoulated Realm to see if it has a primary key set?

Comment: yeah i can browse it throught realm-browser...

Comment: But I dont see anything signifying a primary key..All columns in realm file are strings...i took out the Doubles...and still same error

Comment: I don't believe it's the Double values which are causing the issue. According to the Realm code, you get that error when a primary key is defined and it is not a String or an Int. So Realm does think that a primary key is defined - the question is why? Are you by any chance able to share the project with me? If yes, I can take a look ...

Comment: my dependencies are all over the place...i have to get the project in a diff state to share...im going to make a new project with same realm file, model and manager and see what happens..

Comment: That's actually a great approach :) Simplifying might simply show you what is going on so that you can fix it yourself. If not, just share the simplified project with me and I'll take a look.

Comment: @fahim https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dilini/moreCHOPS.zip

Comment: it worked in a clean project...there must be something going on with cache in previous project....i clear derived data

Comment: The things to try in that situation would be clean project, delete app and re-install, delete derived data, and quit and re-launch Xcode. One of those should hopefully help :)

Comment: btw @fahim what do you use instead of Realm?

Comment: I use [SQLiteDB](https://github.com/FahimF/SQLiteDB) a lightweight SQLite wrapper that I wrote myself. It isn't as snazzy as Realm but I find that it works better for my own needs :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you don't have a Primary Key on models that are "in play". I had models that weren't inside the pre populated realm yet, and THOSE models had Primary Keys on them.

I thought only models "in play/inside the realm" counted.

Any Object subclasses with a Primary Key will cause the error...

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException',
reason: 'Only 'string' and 'int' properties can be designated the 
primary key'`

thanks to https://github.com/bdash
and his [push](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4777)

> Can you do a search in your project for a function named primaryKey to
>   see if you've overlooked one?

and also https://stackoverflow.com/users/3736093/fahim